# How should I fix this - 'int' object is not iterable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, sum, int

Unlike other questions, I'm getting this error *without* using a looping construct.

Here's the code

```
def makes_twenty(n1,n2):
    return ( (sum(n1, n2) == 20) or ((n1 == 20) or (n2 == 20)) )
```

The error I receive - 
`'int' object is not iterable`
[Screenshot of the code with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwPaN.png)

The irony is, if I change this thing - 
`sum(n1, n2)`
Into something like this - 
`(n1 + n2)`
The code works fine.
[Screenshot of corrected code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nw2YD.png)
I wonder what's happening here.

Comment: `sum` tries to *iterate over its first argument*, e.g. `sum([n1, n2])` (or even `sum([n1], n2)`!) would work fine. That's not irony, that's how it's documented as working.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks.  Just copy the text, paste it in your question and format it as code.

Comment: read about `sum` in its [docs page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum), it's all explained pretty well there... also, why use `sum` if you've only 2 numbers? your second option `n1+n2` seems more clear anyway

Answer (score 1):

The `sum` function in python takes first argument as an iterable. You can pass `n1` and `n2` in a list like `sum([n1, n2])`. Since `n1` is integer `sum` function cannot loop over it hence the error `'int' object is not iterable`.

Hope this helps.